# How to transform in ternary operator?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, ternary-operator

I have an if-then-else statement and I want to transform it to a ternary operator, but I do not know why I cannot do it. The code is the following:

```
public Movie create(NewMovieDTO newMovieDTO) {
    Movie movieForSaving = NewMovieDTOToMovie.map(newMovieDTO);
    List<Actor> actorsForSaving = new ArrayList<Actor>();

    movieForSaving.getActors().forEach((actor) -> {
        Optional<Actor> actorInDatabase = actorService
            .findByNameAndSurname(actor.getName(), actor.getSurname());

        if(actorInDatabase.isPresent()) {
            actorForSaving.add(actorInDatabase.get());
        } else {
            actorForSaving.add(actor);
        }
    });
    movieForSaving.setActors(actorForSaving);
    return movieRepository.save(movieForSaving);
}
```

And the code with the ternary operator is:

```
public Movie create(NewMovieDTO newMovieDTO) {
    Movie movieForSaving = NewMovieDTOToMovie.map(newMovieDTO);
    List<Actor> actorsForSaving = new ArrayList<Actor>();

    /*Line 1*/ movieForSaving.getActors().forEach((actor) -> {
        Optional<Actor> actorInDatabase = actorService
            .findByNameAndSurname(actor.getName(), actor.getSurname());
        /*Line 2*/(actorInDatabase.isPresent()) ? actorForSaving.add(actorInDatabase.get()) : actorForSaving.add(actor);
    /*Line 3*/});

    movieForSaving.setActors(actorForSaving);
    return movieRepository.save(movieForSaving);
}
```

The following errors are given by the IDE:

Line 1: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Line 2: Multiple markers at this line

```
            - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment

            - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

            - actorForSaving cannot be resolved to a variable

            - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

            - actorInDatabase cannot be resolved

            - actorForSaving cannot be resolved

            - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
```

Line 3: Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens.

Is it possible to perform a ternary operator here or how can I solve it?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You cannot use a ternary operator, because `ifPresent()` expects the provided function to have a return type of `void`. Furthermore your ternary operator is not a function. And finally ifPresent only runs if you have a non-empty `Optional`, your go to function would be `ifPresentOrElse()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
actorForSaving.add(actorInDatabase.isPresent() ? actorInDatabase.get() : actor);
```

The ternary operator can't be a statement, it's an expression that returns something. In your case, `actorInDatabase.isPresent() ? actorInDatabase.get() : actor` returns an `Actor`.

Another good alternative would be using [`Optional#orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) as -

```
actorForSaving.add(actorInDatabase.orElse(actor));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` is just fine. But if you **really** want to use the conditional operator here, the way to do it is to do it within the argument list to `add`:

```
movieForSaving.getActors().forEach((actor) -> {
    Optional<Actor> actorInDatabase = actorService.findByNameAndSurname(actor.getName(), actor.getSurname());                        
    actorForSaving.add(actorInDatabase.isPresent() ? actorInDatabase.get() : actor);
});
```

You may also be able to use [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)). But your question seemed to be specifically about the conditional operator. *(Which is **a** ternary operator — an operator accepting three operands — but not **the** ternary operator. Granted at the moment it's Java's only ternary operator, but in theory another could be added.)*

Answer (score 2):

The error was already explained. Just the Streamy way to use all and Optional:

```
Movie movieForSaving = NewMovieDTOToMovie.map(newMovieDTO);
List<Actor> actorsForSaving = movieForSaving.getActors().stream()
        .map(actor -> actorService.findByNameAndSurname(actor.getName(),
                 actor.getSurname()).orElse(actor))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

movieForSaving.setActors(actorForSaving);
```